# Where do we need to check when ALB target group shows unhealthy state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After deployment, my targets went to unhealthy state, unable to deploy new version? any ideas, what causing these issue?

Comment: Troubleshooting ALB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

The **Health Check** controls how the distributed health checkers perform their checks.

Typically, the easiest way to is to try and connect to one of the instances directly to see whether it is responding, then debug from there.